# Component's Sizes in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm having major issues aligning the components in GridBagLayout, yes I've read the tutorial by Oracle and tried changing the weightx.

This is how it looks like currently :
[image]

Basically what I need to achieve is:

JTextFields "Nome" and "Filiação" to stretch all the way to the left, just like "Idade" and "Turma"

Bottom JButtons to be the same size, aligned in the middle.

I hope someone can point what I'm missing here.

Here's a sorta SSCCE:

```
 package test1;

import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test");
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

    JLabel labelNome = new JLabel("Nome:");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    jp.add(labelNome, gbc);

    JTextField tfNome = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfNome, gbc);

    JLabel labelIdade = new JLabel("Idade :");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    jp.add(labelIdade, gbc);

    JTextField tfIdade = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfIdade, gbc);

    JLabel labelEndereco = new JLabel("Endereço :");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    jp.add(labelEndereco, gbc);

    JTextField tfEndereco = new JTextField();
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfEndereco, gbc);

    JLabel labelFiliacao = new JLabel("Filiação :");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 1;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    jp.add(labelFiliacao, gbc);

    JTextField tfFiliacao = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfFiliacao, gbc);

    JLabel labelTurma = new JLabel("Turma :");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    jp.add(labelTurma, gbc);

    JTextField tfTurma = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfTurma, gbc);

    JLabel labelDisciplina = new JLabel("Disciplina :");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    jp.add(labelDisciplina, gbc);

    JTextField tfDisciplina = new JTextField();
    gbc.ipadx = 50;
    gbc.ipady = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 3;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    jp.add(tfDisciplina, gbc);

    JButton adicionaDisciplina = new JButton("Adicionar disciplina");
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    jp.add(adicionaDisciplina, gbc);

    JButton limparDisciplina = new JButton("Limpar lista de disciplinas");
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    jp.add(limparDisciplina, gbc);

    JButton botaoSalvar = new JButton("Salvar");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    jp.add(botaoSalvar, gbc);

    JButton botaoCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    jp.add(botaoCancelar, gbc);

    jf.setSize(500, 550);
    jf.add(jp);

    jf.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTextField not aligning in GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011894/jtextfield-not-aligning-in-gridbaglayout)

Comment: It's a follow up with a SSCCE, should I delete it?

Comment: Just update the code on the old post and remove this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JTextFields "Nome" and "Filiação" to stretch all the way to the left, just like "Idade" and "Turma"

Don't know what that means. They are aligned to the left just like the other text fields in that second column.

They may not appear as far left as the other text fields because the "Endereco" label length is longer, so the second column can only start where that ends.

If you want the text fields to have the same size then you need to specify the size of your text field and the GridBagLayout will respect the size. You do this by specifying the columns in the text field when you create the text field:

```
JTextField tfNome = new JTextField(10);
```

Comment: Yes, I meant the size, since both text fields in the row have the same GridBagConstraints settings, why are they not the same size?

Comment: Wow, that was an incredibly simple and easy solution, thanks

Comment: @Mojimi, the GridBagLayout can only assign space based on the size of each grid. Since the "Limpar...." button width is wider than the other labels, the 3rd and 4th columns will occupy more space than the 1st and second columns.

Comment: Oh you're right, I just realized the bottom buttons are the ones doing it, so how can I specify that the gridsize in the buttons is the same as above them? or something like that

Comment: Know what, nvm , I'll use MigLayout ^^

Comment: @Mojimi, MigLayout won't be any different. You need to understand the concepts of a grid. The size of the grid is based on the components size in the different cells of the grid. If you don't like that the button size controls the text field size, then you need to create a separate panel for the buttons. Maybe use a GridLayout.. In any case your original question has been answer, so don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the question has been answer.